# Why do binomial expansions involving surds get closer to integers as they get larger?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, binomial-theorem

Suppose I have a binomial expansion of the form:
$$
(2+\sqrt{3})^n
$$
Why is it that as $n$ approaches $\infty$ that the value of the expansion becomes closer and closer to being an integer?

Comment: What happens if you add $(2-\sqrt{3})^n$ to it?

Comment: All the surd terms cancel out, and it is left as an integer. I can't see how to relate this to the above, however.

Comment: How large is $(2-\sqrt{3})^n$?

Comment: Ohhhhh. (< 1) That's genius. Many thanks!

Comment: Dupe: Does this answer your question? [Why is $(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^{2008}$ so close to an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828329/why-is-sqrt2-sqrt32008-so-close-to-an-integer). See also the questions linked there, and their links... (it's a FAQ).

Comment: And see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48508/242) for further parity anaylsis.

Comment: Wow that's beautiful! Can you somehow use this result to make rational approximations to $\sqrt3$?

Comment: Ah yes, I see now, when $n$ is large and even then you will get quite a rapid convergence of rationals to $\sqrt3$

Comment: What you mean is $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left\{\left(2 + \sqrt{3}\right)^{n}\right\} = \color{red}{\large 0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha_1$ is an [algebraic integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) (which $2 + \sqrt{3}$ is) then it's the root of a monic irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^d + \dots$ with integer coefficients, which here is

$$f(x) = (x - (2 + \sqrt{3}))(x - (2 - \sqrt{3})) = (x - 2)^2 - 3 = x^2 - 4x + 1.$$

This polynomial has some other roots $\alpha_2, \dots \alpha_d$, the *conjugates* of $\alpha_1$, and then you can show in various ways that:

> **Claim:** The sequence
> $$p_n = \sum_{k=1}^d \alpha_k^n$$
> of [power sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) is always an integer.

Here this sequence is $(2 + \sqrt{3})^n + (2 - \sqrt{3})^n$ as Jaap says in the comments. This is easiest to understand in the quadratic case $d = 2$ but it holds more generally.

If it further happens that the other roots $\alpha_2, \dots \alpha_d$ all have absolute value less than $1$, then their contributions to the power sum above decay exponentially as $n \to \infty$, and then for $n$ large enough that the sum of these contributions is less than $\frac{1}{2}$ (which happens quite quickly), $p_n$ will be the closest integer to $\alpha_1^n$. The real algebraic integers with this property are called [Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) and they're somewhat rare but they do exist. The most famous one is probably the golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, whose conjugate is the "other" golden ratio $\varphi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$. The sequence of power sums

$$L_n = \phi^n + \varphi^n$$

is the [Lucas numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number), a close cousin of the more famous Fibonacci numbers, and $|\varphi^n| < \frac{1}{2}$ for $n \ge 2$ so we get that

> **Claim:** For $n \ge 2$, $L_n$ is the closest integer to $\phi^n$.

There's an analogous formula for the Fibonacci numbers which goes

$$F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \varphi^n}{\phi - \varphi}$$

and similarly it implies

> **Claim:** For $n \ge 1$, $F_n$ is the closest integer to $\left[ \frac{\phi^n}{\sqrt{5}} \right]$.

$2 + \sqrt{3}$ has this same kind of relationship to the sequence

$$p_n = (2 + \sqrt{3})^n + (2 - \sqrt{3})^n$$

which can (this is one of the ways to prove it always consists of integers) equivalently be defined as the sequence satisfying $p_0 = 2, p_1 = 4$ and the recurrence relation

$$p_{n+2} = 4 p_{n+1} - p_n.$$

This sequence begins $2, 4, 14, 52, \dots$ and I don't think it has a name but it's [A003500](http://oeis.org/A003500) in the OEIS.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post this as another question, but I know the answer now and I think it's better to post it here. My question was going to be:

Can we use this fact: "Binomial expansions of some surds get closer to an integer as $n \to \infty$"  to get *arbitrarily good* rational approximations of those surds?

The $2$ in the question of this thread may muddy the waters, so let's use another example: $(\sqrt13 + 3)^n$.

$(\sqrt13 + 3)^n + (\sqrt13 - 3)^n = 2[ \ (\sqrt13)^n + \binom{n}{2}(\sqrt13)^{n-2}(-3)^2 +  ... + \binom{n}{n-2}(\sqrt13)^{2}(-3)^{n-2} + (-3)^n\ ] \implies$

$(\sqrt13 + 3)^n - 2[ \ (\sqrt13)^n + \binom{n}{2}(\sqrt13)^{n-2}(-3)^2 +  ... + \binom{n}{n-2}(\sqrt13)^{2}(-3)^{n-2} + (-3)^n\ ] = (\sqrt13 - 3)^n$

$\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, which was the little calculation Jaap Scherphuis indicated towards in his comment.

I guess the answer to my question is yes: consider when $n$ is a large and even number, pretend the right hand side is $0$ (which is appropriate) and re-arrange.

(Maybe it also works for odd $n$, but you don't need to consider that now that you can see it works for even $n$ ).

I'm not sure of the convergence rate of this approximation to rationals compared to some other methods, but perhaps that's an investigation for another day.